# triggers in different schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, schema

I am new to SQL Server.

I have to write a trigger for inserting and updating table in different schema in MS SQL.

Example:

> TEMP1 table in one Schema
>
> TEMP2 table in another Schema

How can this be done?

Comment: What is the table structure - i.e. do you have some relation between temp1 and temp2? Are they identical tables in two different schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long the SCHEMAs have the same owner (The AUTHORIZATION bit in [CREATE SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx)) you'd simply refer to the objects using 2 part names.

See [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) too

```
create trigger MyTrigger on Schema1.Table1
for insert
as
set nocount on
insert Schema2.Table2 (...)
select (..) from inserted
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the problem completely, but basic syntax would look like this:

```
create trigger MyTrigger on Schema1.Table1
after insert, update
as
    insert Schema2.Table2 values(1, 'test', ...)

    update Schema3.Table3
    set Name = 'XX'
    where Id = 1
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create multiple triggers to handle different events on different tables.

Refer to [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).